# git common submodule of submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have an application `main` which consists of multiple submodules `A`, `B` and `utility_functions`:
Both of these submodules `A` and `B` by itself include the submodule `utility_functions`.

```
main
|
|---- A
|     |
|     |---- utility_functions
|
|---- B
|     |
|     |---- utility_functions
|
|---- utility_functions
```

Right now I have the `utility_functions` three times in my project. 
Usually `sub_A`, `sub_B` and `main` should all point to the same commit of `utility_functions`.

It is necessary that the code from the repository `A` is run-able by itself.
If I only clone `A` it should include my `utility_functions`

```
A
|
|---- utility_functions
```

Is there a way to only tell my submodules included in the main repository to rely on the same `utility_functions`? Or does this break the idea of submodules because they can point to different commits? Or is this simply a bad idea?

```
main
|
|---- A
|     |
|     |----
|         |
|---- B   |
|     |   |
|     |   |
|     |   |
|---- utility_functions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or does this break the idea of submodules because they can point to different commits?

Yes, that wouldn't be practical precisely because of that reason.

If you are sure that `A` and `B` should *always* reference the same version of `utility_functions`, then clone your main repo and update only `A`, `B` and `utility_functions` (without the recursive option), and make a symlink from `A/utility_functions` and `B/utility_functions` to `../utility_functions`.