# Avoid duplication of same git submodule within one project

Tags: git, directory, clone, git-submodules

I didn't find anything related so I thought I might ask. Say in a project I have the following structure:

```
my_project
├── .git
└── submodules
    ├── database_client
    │   └── submodules
    │       ├── io_lib
    │       │   └── .git
    │       └── JSON_parser // <--
    │           └── .git
    └─ JSON_parser // <-- one of those is not needed..
        └── .git
```

As you can see, the `JSON_parser` submodule is a dependency of both, my main project and a submodule that I'm including. So what I suppose is going to happen is that git is going to clone it twiced when using `git submodule update --init --recursive`. Is there a way to avoid that und only use the submodule once in my project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116331/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054855/7976758

Comment: Thank you. I see symlinks seem to be the solution. Would this also work on windows (Afaik windows doesn't know the concept of symlinks)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5917249/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664406/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+symlinks+windows